# how to call controller function from run block only with classname in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call controller function from run block.

HTML

```
<div class="yourcontroller component section" ng-app="" data-ng-controller="mainController" data-module="yourcontroller">
</div>
```

And inside my run I'm trying to call the controller function like below

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("yourcontroller");
var scope = angular.element(result);
scope.yourControllerMethod();
```

I'm getting `yourControllerMethod` is not defined

Please don't refer me the answer like below to use id instead of classname

```
 var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('yourcontainer')).scope();
 scope.yourControllerMethod();
```

But I don't have id and I can't create id due to dependency. Is there anyway to call controller function from run block with the use of **classname not with id**.

**Edit:**

```
angular.module('modulename', [])

    .controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window ) {

    $scope.yourControllerMethod = function(){
                    console.log("inside yourControllerMethod");
                };

    }])

.run(function($rootScope, $log, $window) {
            // get the first element with class 'yourcontroller'.
              var result = document.getElementsByClassName("yourcontroller")[0];
           // create a angular element from this element.
              var aElm = angular.element(result);
          // get this element's scope;
              var scope = aElm.scope();
          // call scope function.
              scope.yourControllerMethod();
        });
```

Comment: You can try `var result = document.getElementsByClassName("yourcontroller")[0];` because unlike `getElementById(...)` the `getElementsByClassName(...)` function returns more then 1 element.

Comment: can you please ellaborate this as an answer.

Comment: Even easier would be `document.querySelector('[data-ng-controller="mainController"]')` but what's with `ng-app=""`? That doesn't make sense

Comment: @Phil Can you please ellaborate how to use this?

Comment: No, but I suggest you go read the documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Also, what is the class name? Is it "yourcontroller" or "RetrieveCart"?

Comment: yourcontroller only..

Comment: modified my code. pls check.. I have 3 classnames there

Comment: I feel like you're going about this the wrong way. What is it exactly you want to achieve? Why do you have to try and call the method from the module's `run` method?

Comment: I'd say the reason it's not working is because the `run` block is executed *before* the controller is created and the scope assigned to your element

Comment: I just want to call yourControllerMethod from run block..with the use of classname yourcontroller . that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName(...)` function returns a collection of elements not just one element. To get the first element from this collection you can use `[0]`, eg: `getElementsByClassName(...)[0]`.
Beside that, you also have to call the `yourControllerMethod()` function on the angular element's scope not on the element itself.

```
// get the first element with class 'yourcontroller'.
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("yourcontroller")[0];
// create a angular element from this element.
var aElm = angular.element(result);
// get this element's scope;
var scope = aElm.scope();
// call scope function.
scope.yourControllerMethod();
```

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yourControllerMethod' of undefined

Comment: Edited my question with the updated code.. i m getting the above error

Comment: @UI_Dev The `data-ng-controller` attribute value should be set to `myCtrl`. Use the same name as in the JavaScript `.controller('myCtrl'.....)`.

Comment: Yeah I modified that too, and getting the same error

Comment: @UI_Dev Are you sure that the first element with class `RetrieveCart` is inside the element that you set the controller on ?

Comment: Yeah that is yourcontroller , but I have three classes in the div..pls see my updated code